# Use list comprehension to find largest int value in kwargs that also contain a certain substring

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Here's my code because I think it's easier to explain what I'm trying to do by showing what I'm doing first.

Let's say these are my kwargs passed to a function:

```
kwargs = {fastperiod=20, slowperiod=10, r=100}
```

So I am trying to find the largest value of kwargs that also contain the substring `period`. In this case that would mean `20`.

I am currently doing this with:

```
periods = []
    for kwarg in kwargs:
        if 'period' in kwarg:
            periods.append(kwargs.get(kwarg))
    max_ = max(periods)
```

Which is not very terse. I feel like there has to be a way to achieve this with list comprehension.

The best I could come up with is:

```
max_ = max([i for i in kwargs.get(i) if 'period' in i])
```

But I get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment`

I am not sure how to check if kwarg contains period and then return the int value assigned to it at the same time.

Comment: `max(v for k,v in kwargs.items() if 'period' in k)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `kwargs.items()` to get the key and value as you iterate.

```
max([v for k, v in kwargs.items() if "period" in k])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work friend

```
kwargs = {'fastperiod':20, 'slowperiod':10, 'r':100}

max_ = max([kwargs[kwarg] for kwarg in kwargs if 'period' in kwarg])
```